# Java Open URL Inside of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, url, jframe, jdialog

I was wondering if there is a way to open a URL inside of a JFrame or JDialog. I need this to protect the URL.

Is there a way to run a browser inside of a Java component such as a JFrame or a JDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [should](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) be what you are looking for, a web browser component that you can easily use in your SWING application

Comment: Is there a better way? I don't want to include all these files with my application ...

Comment: Well if you want to have a browser embedded in your application than  I am afraid you have no choice

Comment: That sucks. Okay! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

This would only make the URL secret for dummies. With a network sniffer like Ethereal, it would be trivial to know which requests are made by your application. Security through obscurity is always a bad idea.

If you want to do that for other reasons, JEditorPane is able to display HTML and load it from a URL, but its HTML capabilities are very limited compared to a real browser.