# How to open web page URL in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I have this code which creates a JFrame:

```
/* FrameDemo.java requires no other files. */
public class bot {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();

             }
        });
     }
 }
```

And I have the following code for opening a web page URL:

```
public class fun {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("www.google.lt");
            Desktop desktop = null;
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            }
            if (desktop != null)
                desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (IOException ioe) { 

            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
            use.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I join these codes? And make that the web page would appear inside JFrame? Maybe there is command include like in php?

Comment: i guess you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548706/java-open-url-inside-of-a-jframe

Comment: `    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setPage(new URL("http://www.java2s.com"));
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(editorPane));`

Comment: In the standard library, there is `JEditorPane` with very basic HTML support, or you can use the modern `WebView` from JavaFX via `JFXPanel`.

Comment: @xehpuk +1 for the Java-FX suggestion.  `JEditorPane` was never intended as a browser component.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WebView component of the javafx component library (now included with Java) and wrap it inside a JFXPanel so you can use it in your Swing UI.

Alternatively, try the commercial jxBrowser component from TeamDev.